# How to keep both cursor and PlaceholderText displayed at the same time in a QLineEdit?

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4

I have a `QLineEdit` with a `PlaceholderText`.

I want to clear the `PlaceholderText` only when a person starts typing, else the blinking cursor and `PlacehoderText` both should be there in that `QLineEdit`.

It is the first field of the page, so I have set the focus to this `QLineEdit`, but the `PlaceholderText` disappears as soon as this page is displayed.

Please suggest if I'll have to add a SIGNAL/SLOT for this `QLIneEdit`, so that the `PlaceholderText` doesn't get cleared off.

Answer (score 1):

In PyQt4 it's not a bug but a feature. You can't edit this behaviour. In PyQt5, the placeholder text is shown until the text is not empty.

A simple way to solve problem is to focus some way before `QLintEdit`. When the user press `TAB` button, next focus is `QLintEdit`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class LE(QtGui.QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, starttext="Sample"):
        QtGui.QLineEdit.__init__(self, parent)
        self.start = True
        self.setText(starttext)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.text():
            if self.start:
                self.clear()
                self.start = False
                e.accept()           
        QtGui.QLineEdit.keyPressEvent(self,e)
```